# How to pass an array to a template?

Tags: theming, 8, hooks

I am trying to get my first module to work which is supposed to render an array in his own template file.

1) I got an array of variables and return it in my controller

```
        array(
        '#theme' => 'myTheme',
        '#test_var' => $this->t('Test Value'),
        '#array' => array('key'=>$myArray),
        );
```

2) in my .module I declare the hook_theme()

```
  return array(
'myTheme' => array(
  'variables' => array(
    'test_var' => '',
    'array' => array(),
    ),
),
```

);

3) Then I would like to print the variables
I am sure I missing something, and if I'm missing basic knowledge please let me know. I'm sure something is  wrong in the hook_theme since I don't know how to iterate my array in the template file.

```
<p>test_var: {{ test_var }}</p>
<p>{{ array }}</p>
```

If somebody could point me in the right direction, that would be nice :)

edit: the "Test Value" is rendering just fine

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The variable names in the render array and theme hook need to match:

```
array(
  '#theme' => 'myTheme',
  '#test_var' => $this->t('Test Value'),
  '#doubles' => array('key'=>$myArray),
);
```

Iterating an array in Twig is pretty straightforward:

```
{% for key,value in doubles %}
  Key : {{ key }}
  Value : {{ value }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: wow that was quick, thank you.
the variables name match, that was a mistake i edited.

i will try that solution

Comment: Unfortunately that was not the solution  

i also got an error message for each of my array keys  
  User error: "46" is an invalid render array key in Drupal\Core\Render\Element::children() (line 97 of /homepages/17/d628339351/htdocs/thesis/Drupal822/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Render/Element.php)

Comment: If you print an array Drupal will try to render it as a render array, so you just need do something with the nested array. Might be getting a value like `value.foo`, or looping over it to get at the values and so on

Comment: just as a follow up, your answer was totally correct, and the final solution was that since my array wasnt associative but rather a simple array and therefor the controller return looked even simplier: '#array' => $myArray. thats it ;)

Comment: @GinTonic What was the code in .module file.