# Passing an array of object from custom module to template in drupal 8

Tags: theming, 8

Follow [this](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/221053/how-to-pass-an-array-to-a-template) about passing an array to template. But my array is array of object so I'm getting some errors on the page, this is the one of them:

> User error: "0" is an invalid render array key in
>   Drupal\Core\Render\Element::children() (line 97 of
>   core/lib/Drupal/Core/Render/Element.php)

**This is my code :**

**Controller**

```
  public function content() {
      return array(
        '#theme' => 'my_page', 
        '#text' => "Lorem Ipsum",       
        '#myvariable' => array('key' => $myArrayofObjects),
      );
  }
```

**mymodule.module**

```
function my_page($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  return array(
    'my_page' => array(
        'variables' => array(
            'text' => NULL,
            'myvariable' => array(),
        ),
    ),
  );
}
```

**my-page.html.twig**

```
<p>Test twig template!</p>    
<p>{{text}}</p>

{% for key, value in myvariable %}
  Key : {{ key }}
  Value : {{ value }}
{% endfor %}
```

**This is the array :**

```
Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [name] => User1
                [user_id] => 1
                [email] => user1@website.com
            )

        [1] => stdClass Object
            (
                [name] => User2
                [user_id] => 2
                [email] => user2@website.com
            )

        [2] => stdClass Object
            (
                [name] => User3
                [user_id] => 3
                [email] => user3@website.com
            )
     )
```

How the best way to pass an array of object from module to template and render or loop it using twig engine?

Answer (score 4):

In your controller why you are using like this

```
'#myvariable' => array('key' => $myArrayofObjects),
```

Change it as

```
'#myvariable' => $myArrayofObjects,
```

and in **my-page.html.twig**

```
<p>Test twig template!</p>    
<p>{{text}}</p>

{% for key, value in myvariable %}
  Key : {{ key }}
  Name : {{ value.name }}
  User ID : {{ value.user_id }}
  Email : {{ value.email }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thank's @AAjay Reddy, finally it works. 

If you are willing, can you give an explain why `#myvariable => array('key' => $myArrayofObjects),` changed to `#myvariable => $myArrayofObjects` ? For my knowladge. Thanks

Comment: @UgyAstro - You don't need `'key'` because when you do the `for` loop in the Twig, it will automatically associate the index with `key` and each element in the array with `value`. 

In your example, the `key` index variable will be the `'key'` string and the `value` will be the actual array of objects.

Comment: @edwardchiapet given correct explanation, thanks edwardchiapet